# Who ruled "Hutt Space"?

Tags: star-wars

It is often portrayed that the [Hutt Clan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hutt_Clan) rule a section of the galaxy, but who took charge of the clan? In addition, who took over from [Jabba](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jabba_Desilijic_Tiure) (if he was the leader) after his death in ROTJ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the Databank, the [Hutt Clan](http://www.starwars.com/databank/hutt-clan) is governed by a five-Hutt council (emphasis mine):

> The Hutt Clan was one of the most powerful crime families in the galaxy, making riches through smuggling and myriad illegal businesses across worlds. **They were governed by the Hutt Grand Council, a committee of elder Hutts** that would advise on strategy and make decisions on inter-family disputes.

The Grand Council was introduced in the CG-animated *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* series, and counted Jabba among its members until his death. A brief mention in the canon novel *Aftermath*, set mere months after the events of *Return of the Jedi*, reveal that Jabba's position had yet to be filled by that point:

> I know that things are changing. Not just in the galaxy, but here at home, too. The Hutts still haven’t shaken out who's next up to fill Jabba's throne — if you can call that flat slab of his a throne.
>
> <sup>*Aftermath* Interlude: Tatooine</sup>

As far as I know, the issue of Hutt leadership has not been visited beyond this point of the timeline.

As a matter of interest, this is substantially similar in Legends, though (naturally) there's a [much deeper history](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hutt_Ruling_Council) portrayed in those materials.

Comment: But who are the Hutt on the council? I only know of Jabba (who is gone), _Pizza the Hutt_ and _Sunglass Hutt_ (deal with it).

Comment: @n_b During the Clone Wars, we [also](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/hunt-for-ziro-trivia-gallery) had Oruba, Marlo, Arok, and Gorga. None of them are quite as noteworthy as Jabba, and the Council's composition in other eras of galactic history is unknown

Comment: @JasonBaker Wasn't Gardulla part of it as well, as she's mentioned many times in the episodes focusing on the Hutt Council.

Comment: @CBredlow I haven't watched the episodes in a while, but the trivia gallery (link in my last comment) says that Gardulla was acting as Jabba's proxy, which suggests she wasn't normally part of the Council